# Sharing Contracts with Account Teams

Tags: account, sharing, account-teams, teams

I currently use my sharing settings to hide "deactivated" accounts - so I set them to private and only show the accounts where my deactivated flag = false.

Since sharing settings have contracts under the same setting as accounts, how would i go about only sharing contracts to certain people?

And in more detail, how to go about using "Account Teams" to show who to share contracts with..

I only want people under an account team to be able to see the contracts within that account.

Thank you!!

Comment: when you say "how to go about using "Account Teams" to show who to share contracts with..", are you still talking about deactivated accounts' contracts (or) active accounts contracts?